# What are valid appJar stretch function arguments

Tags: python

So far I've been attempting to create a 2 factor authentication script in python. It works very well now and I wanted to create a gui since this will be running nearly 24/7 on a raspberry pi.

TLDR; I don't understand what the docs mean by "stretch. Pass a string describing if rows/columns should stretch, to fill the entire GUI. "

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyotp
import os
import sys
import math
import time
from appJar import gui
udstart = 1
app = gui("2FA Keys","480x320")
def count(n):
        while n >= 0:
                time.sleep(1)
                n -= 1
        if n == 0:
                return 1

#Keygenertor function pass the base32 code
def keyGen(secret):
        secretcalc = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
        code = secretcalc.now()
        Lcode = list(code)
        Lcode.insert(3, " ")
        Ocode = ''.join(Lcode)
        return Ocode

#INIT CODES GO HERE
CoinbaseCode = keyGen("3JCAJVDGIW4KHUHL")
SiaCoinCode = keyGen("PFFO3KKKRQL6ACU5")

app.stretch(columns)
app.setFont(50)
app.addLabel("l2", "Sia Coin: " + SiaCoinCode, 0,0,0,0)
app.setLabelbg("l2", "blue")
app.addLabel("l1", "Coinbase: " + CoinbaseCode, 1,0,0,0) #Coinbase 2FA
app.setLabelBg("l1", "red")



while True:
        if udstart == 1:
                break
        else:
                time.sleep(30)
        break
def update():
        #UPDATE CODES GO HERE
        CoinbaseCode = keyGen("3JCAJVDGIW4KHUHL") #Coinbase
        SiaCoinCode = keyGen("PFFO3KKKRQL6ACU5")
        app.setLabel("l2", "Sia Coin: " + SiaCoinCode)
        app.setLabelBg("l2", "blue")
        app.setLabel("l1", "Coinbase: " + CoinbaseCode)
        app.setLabelBg("l1", "red")
#profit???
udstart = 0
app.registerEvent(update)
app.go()
```

I have no idea what to pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the appJar [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jarvisteach/appJar/blob/appJar/appJar/appjar.py), you can identify what you should pass for `stretch`:

Looking at how `strech` is used:

```
def setStretch(self, exp):
    self.setExpand(exp)
...
stretch = property(getStretch, setStretch)
```

Looking at the source for the `setExpand` we see the possible values for strech:

```
def setExpand(self, exp):
    if exp.lower() == "none":
        self.containerStack[-1]['expand'] = "NONE"
    elif exp.lower() == "row":
        self.containerStack[-1]['expand'] = "ROW"
    elif exp.lower() == "column":
        self.containerStack[-1]['expand'] = "COLUMN"
    else:
        self.containerStack[-1]['expand'] = "ALL"
```

As a result, the possible strings are (case insensitive) **"None", "Row", "Column", or anything else** (which will result in **"ALL"**).

Answer (score 0):

It's also documented here: http://appjar.info/pythonWidgetLayout/#set-stretch-sticky

- none, row, column, both